# looping through dynamic data type variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am getting a bunch of response form the webservice in json format. I am using the above code to fetch data from the json response

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_siteResp);
var date = data[0].refreshInfo.lastDataUpdateAttempt.date;
Transaction = date.ToString();
```

using the above code I am only able to fetch a single record.How do I fetch multiple records in c#.Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate over data if it is a collection

```
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_siteResp);

    foreach (dynamic d in data)
    {
        var x = d.DoSomeThing;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.....I am new to Json.Can you provide me with your mail id for further help????

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should work:

```
var result = data.Select(x => x.refreshInfo.lastDataUpdateAttempt.date.ToString());
```

This returns the value of the property for every member within your `data`-list. Assumes further that your `data` contains any kind of `Enumerable`.